# How to speed up the VirMIDI (MIDI) ports detection and the sequencer creation by java on Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, midi, java

I installed the snd-virmidi kernel module in order to have Virtual MIDI ports in java. Thanks to these MIDI ports, java can connect non-java MIDI software synthesizer on Linux.

But, openjdk takes a long time to detect those Virtual MIDI ports ... And further more, it detects a long list of virtual ports while "aconnect" command line tells me there are 4 virtual ports only ...

I've observed this behavior in impro-visor (java software) and in my current development  (a MIDI application).

I use openjdk 7 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the code i used to test time response of different key MIDI method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    long start = new Date().getTime();
    Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer(true);
    long end = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("getSequencer true end : " + (end - start) + " ms");

    start = new Date().getTime();
    sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer(false);
    end = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("getSequencer false end : " + (end - start) + " ms");

    start = new Date().getTime();
    List<String> outputDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Obtain information about all the installed synthesizers.
    MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();

    // Scan all found devices and check to see what type they are
    MidiDevice device = null;
    for (MidiDevice.Info info : infos) {
        try {
            device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info);
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            continue;
        }
        if (device instanceof Synthesizer) {
            outputDeviceList.add(info.getName());
            continue;
        }
        if (!(device instanceof Synthesizer)
                && !(device instanceof Sequencer)) {
            // The device is an instance of a hardware Midi port.
            int numReceivers = device.getMaxReceivers();

            if (numReceivers != 0) {
                outputDeviceList.add(info.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    end = new Date().getTime();
    System.out.println("getAllOutputDevice end : " + (end - start) + " ms");
}
```

The code above has been run on an i3 intel processor (Ubuntu 12.04) with openjdk:

```
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```

and gives the following output:

```
getSequencer true end : 20811 ms
getSequencer false end : 6945 ms
getAllOutputDevice end : 13933 ms
```

With the snd-virmidi kernel module unloaded, the result is:

```
getSequencer true end : 412 ms
getSequencer false end : 5 ms
getAllOutputDevice end : 11 ms
```

Is there a way to speed up the java virtual MIDI ports detection and the sequencer intialization process ?